# Downloading a static resource does not work

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin20

I have a vaadin project with Spring integration. The project has a single static resource (pdf file) that should be served from the web application, via vaadin's Anchor element.

According to https://vaadin.com/docs/v20/flow/advanced/loading-resources#static-resources the pdf document is placed in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/documentation.pdf.

When starting the web application directly in my IDE (IntelliJ) the download work as expected. However, running the web application from the maven-generated jar, the download request simply returns "Could not navigate to 'documentation.pdf'". There is no INFO, WARN, ... log entry in the application's log. The documentation.pdf is located in META-INF/resources/documentation.pdf.

vaadin version: 20.0.3
firefox version: 89.0.2

What can I do?

Comment: How do you download it? Directly via URL or do you have a component?

Comment: And how did you build it with Maven? mvn package -Pproduction?

Comment: I crated a minimal example and it works. So I assume that you didn't build in production mode

Comment: Do you have the `download` attribute set? Please share some code.

Comment: If there is no log output, is there log output for the packages at all, that make you think, that should give an error? Have you tried ramping up the log-level? Is the PDF inside the JAR? What relative path are you using to reference the file?  How do you run the jar (far jar?  deployed was war? ...)

Comment: To answer the questions:
1. Via Anchor that is placed in a component.
2. The project is build in production mode.
3. What download attribute?
4. The PDF is inside the fat jar located at META-INF/resources/documentation.pdf. The fat jar is used in a docker container, which finally is deployed in an K8s environment. When running the docker container via e.g., docker-compose locally I get the same response "Could not navigate ...". I'm using the relative path documentation.pdf.
5. So far I haven't ramped up the log level.

Comment: The problem is independent from docker/docker-compose and occurs also when I run the fat jar directly.